# Identify idle or minimized process

Tags: process-management, snmp

I'm trying to know if some GUI process is idle o minimized in Linux, using `Net-SNMP`.

I've been doing research and as far as I know, SNMP seems to be designed for monitoring services, not processes run by regular users.

I've found just one MIB object, **hrSWRunStatus** ([RFC 2790](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2790)), which has only four running statuses: **running(1)**, **runnable(2)**, **notRunnable(3)** and **invalid(4)**, but testing by maximizing and minimizing some GUI applications don't display any changes in their respective statuses, in fact, every process listed with `snmpwalk` has **runnable(2)** status, except one: `snmpd` which is listed as **running(1)**.

```
# snmpwalk -v 2c -c public localhost .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.4.2.1.7 | grep "running(1)"
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunStatus.920 = INTEGER: running(1)
# snmpwalk -v 2c -c public localhost .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.4.2.1.2 | grep 920
HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSWRunName.920 = STRING: "snmpd"
```

Even using `ps` I don't see a change in the status of a process I'm using at the moment (except for `htop`). If `htop` is running in a terminal console, like `konsole` and I'm writing a text with `kate`, none of those processes has the status "**R**" (running or runnable), just "**S**" (interruptible sleep), which I found weird, but is supposed to be in that way...  https://supportcenter.checkpoint.com/supportcenter/portal?eventSubmit_doGoviewsolutiondetails=&solutionid=sk112953

So, how can I know, in Linux, if some process is idle or minimized...?

Comment: Processes cannot be minimized, only windows can. There is no relationship between the status of a window and the status of a process.

Comment: @AlexP so, I've should ask "how can I know if some GUI software is minimized?"... is that possible?

Comment: Not with Net-SNMP. You would have to communicate with the window manager process of your desktop environment to get that information. (This sounds like [an XY problem.](http://xyproblem.info/) What is the problem you're trying to solve by finding out if a GUI program is minimized or not?)

Comment: @telcoM I want to record the time used with some applications, if the app is minimized or in the background then it's not being used, if the app is the foreground and is active then is being used. Basically, I want to develop my own time tracking app, using open source tools on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments you said you want to develop a time tracking app, for tracking application usage. I guess you might do it by tracking *which window is the active one at any given time*.

To do that, you would need to get access to the user's X11 session, and then repeatedly query its X11 property named `_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW`.

This code example might be helpful to you:
https://github.com/UltimateHackingKeyboard/current-window-linux/blob/master/get-current-window.c

If the system uses Wayland instead of classic X11, unfortunately Wayland might require its own solution; I simply don't know enough about that one.

Comment: looking for more info about the X11 `_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW` property I got a couple of commands that manage X11 properties this post that answers my question: https://superuser.com/questions/382616/detecting-currently-active-window, so I have two apps: `xdotool` (very simple to manage but doesn't manage all the X11 properties) and `xprop` (hard to understand but very robust, managing all the X11 properties), so I choose the last one.